# Stock clustering for Statistical Arbitrage Trading

Tags: arbitrage, machine-learning, pairs-trading

Has ML based stock-clustering been practically adapted by the industry in arbitrage trading strategies like pairs trading for forming pairs instead of other traditional techniques like cointegration?